# Optimizing foreach loop in C#, adding threads?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, math, foreach

So've made a mail filtering program, it works just okey on a "test" environment. But when I wanted to try it out on a real datatbase set, waited an hour and probably could wait another 10 hours for the result.

Here is my loop:

```
foreach (var word in mail)
            {               
                foreach (var wordInSpam in countsWordOccurenceSpam)
                {
                    foreach (var wordInOk in countsWordOccurenceOk)
                    {
                        if (countsWordOccurenceOk.ContainsKey(word.Key) && countsWordOccurenceSpam.ContainsKey(word.Key))
                        {
                            if (word.Key == wordInOk.Key && word.Key == wordInSpam.Key)
                            {
                             //math
                            }
                        }
                        else if (countsWordOccurenceOk.ContainsKey(word.Key) && (!countsWordOccurenceSpam.ContainsKey(word.Key)))
                        {
                            if (word.Key == wordInOk.Key)
                            {
                             //math
                            }
                        }
                        else if (countsWordOccurenceSpam.ContainsKey(word.Key) && (!countsWordOccurenceOk.ContainsKey(word.Key)))
                        {
                            if (word.Key == wordInSpam.Key)
                            {
                            //math
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //math
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

mail is dictionary for a mail "to check", that contains words and counter to each of them, countsWordOccurenceSpam/Ok are dictionaries for multiple mails, that contains words and their counter.

Looks like this:

```
   if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        foreach (string filename in openFileDialog.FileNames)
        {
            myOkMail.Add(filename);

        }
    }

    string[] okFiles = myOkMail.ToArray();


    var logFile2 = okFiles
        .SelectMany(i => System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(i)).ToList();

     countsWordOccurenceOk = okFiles
        .SelectMany(i => System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(i)
        .SelectMany(line => line.Split(new[] { ' ', ',', '.', '?', '!', '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        .Distinct())
        .GroupBy(word => word)
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

The program worked flawlessly when I was testing like 50 mails, but when there is 50k spam mails, and 50k ham mails it.. just no. Processor used is on around 10% level only.

Also, it might be worth noting, the "math" part is almost the same in every checked category, and looks like this:

```
                else if (countsWordOccurenceSpam.ContainsKey(word.Key) && (!countsWordOccurenceOk.ContainsKey(word.Key)))
                {
                    if (word.Key == wordInSpam.Key)
                    {
                        totals = wordInSpam.Value;

                        fprob_spam = ((double)wordInSpam.Value) / ile_spam;

                        sum_spam = (((weight * probability) + (totals * fprob_spam)) / (totals + weight));
                        sum_ok = ((weight * probability) / (totals + weight)); 

                        sum_spam = Math.Pow(sum_spam, word.Value);
                        sum_ok = Math.Pow(sum_ok, word.Value);

                        cos = countsWordOccurenceOk.Count;
                        wp_spam = Math.Pow(sum_spam, (1/cos));
                        last_o = Math.Pow(sum_ok, (1 / cos));

                        wp_spam_1 = wp_spam_1 * wp_spam;
                        last_o_1 = last_o_1 * last_o;

                    }
                }
```

Yeah, looks awful. And also, one thing I still didn't get into is that I had to use to get the right results:

```
                        cos = countsWordOccurenceOk.Count;
                        wp_spam = Math.Pow(sum_spam, (1/cos));
                        last_o = Math.Pow(sum_ok, (1 / cos));
```

because it was multiplying it by the number of words in database.

Help appreciated,
Kenichi

Comment: `System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach` would help you to split this into many parallel threads

Comment: @Jibbow is right but this would only break it down from a couple of hours to (say) 1/8th of this (if you have an really good server) - so you might rethink your algorithm instead ;)

Comment: for example: why do you loop over all words in you mail, and your dicts if you then go on and check if your word is in any of the dictionaries - both the inner loops are not really needed ...

Comment: @CarstenKönig well, good point, need to check how it works out.

Comment: To put it in numbers, if you have 100 spam and 100 OK words, you increase processing time by 10K times.

Comment: @CarstenKönig one question, how could I then use for example: wordInSpam.Key/wordInSpam.Value from dictionary, not iterating through it in foreach loop?

Comment: you can use [`TryGetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx) or if you know it's there via `ContainsKey` just `myDict[key]` to get the value

Comment: @CarstenKönig so something like this?if (word.Key == countsWordOccurenceSpam[key]) and countsWordOccurenceSpam.TryGetValue(word.Key, out totals)

Comment: no - more like `if (countWordOccurenceSpam.TryGetValue(word.Key, out value) && ... ) { ... you can use value here ... }`

Comment: @CarstenKönig yes, this one is working but, by saying end I meant two different operations sorry. I get value (int) that way, but I have to compare if words (key, string) are equal to make operations. And using TryGetKey doesn't really work (no method like this).

Comment: You don't need to do `cos = countsWordOccurenceOk.Count;` each time, it will be the same, so you should define cos once at the top.

Comment: @CarstenKönig I've made a significant improvement using just those words about deleting those two loops, and would like to add this as an answear to my problem. But cant really select it as my answear.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way you could try out would be using the `Parallel.ForEach` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx)) which can run the iterations of a loop in different threads.

You could try out replacing the outer ForEach and see if you notice any performance differences. It should look something like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(mail, this.DoWork);
```

And then you can you can call your next Loop in your DoWork method:

```
public void DoWork(String word)
{
    foreach (var wordInSpam in countsWordOccurenceSpam)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyway to use word.Key in this scenario?

Comment: Ensure you are using thread-safe collections such as the ones provided in `System.Collections.Concurrent` if you are going to implement `Parallel.ForEach` or similar methods.